# correct status code / description returning empty collection as web response

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I have a method that returns all items purchased by user like this

```
http://myapihost/items/{user_id}
```

Some users won't have any purchased items, so items will be `items = [];`.

Whats the correct response when returning an empty collection?

```
//pass empty array with 200 OK
Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, items);
```

Or

```
//pass message with 200 OK
Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, "No items were purchased by the user.");
```

The problem with passing `string` with 200 OK is that end user would be forced to do another check before de-serializing the response to `List<Item>` as normally 200 OK returns `List<Item>`

Or

```
Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NoContent, "No items were purchased by the user.");
```

RFC defines NoContent as

> The server has fulfilled the request but does not need to return an entity-body, and might want to return updated metainformation.

So this response cannot be correct, right?

Or

```
Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, "No items were purchased by the user.");
```

RFC defines NotFound as

> The server has not found anything matching the Request-URI.

So this response cannot be correct too, right?

Or is there any other response?

Comment: It's as much a matter of taste as anything else. I can see nothing wrong with either returning an empty set or returning `NotFound`.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever, I am more inclined to returning an empty set. Will `NotFound` be correct as per specification?

Comment: Isn't this a similar question as : Do you return "null" or an "empty list instance" from a method. Personally i like to keep things consistent. I would opt for the `empty array back´. Based on:
- We did find it.. (it's an empty list, we wanted 'the list of items', not "at least one item in an iterator). Therefor "not found" feels wrong.
- Client doesn't want to write "if" on the response of this request, just a consistent "foreach" what the expected type is for a collection of items.
my 2cts.

Comment: @MarvinSmit: that is not a similar for me. I am looking at best practice on which status should my response be! I am also thinking about 200 OK with empty array though. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sending the empty array would be best option for 2 reason

1. The end client would always expect an consistent object of course it can be null but the client code would be lot cleaner
2. The data transmitted via the wire would be minimum for the null case rather sending a message as client would be responsible for the message and the language in which message would be shown